# Regular Expression to extract Named Entities from text just based on capitalization

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want a regex in Python which extracts one or multiple occurrences of words starting with capital letters unless the word occurs in the first word. I know it's not a robust and consistent method but it'll solve my problem as I don't want to use any statistical method (e.g. as in NLTK or StanfordNER).

**Examples:**

```
extract('His name is John Wayne.')
```

should return ['John Wayne'].

```
extract('He is The President of Neverland.')
```

should return ['The President', 'Neverland'] because they are capitalized words and they don't occur at the beginning of a sentence.

**another example:**

```
extract('He came home. Although late, it was nice to have Patrick there.')
```

should return ['Patrick'] because 'He' and 'Although' occur at the beginning of a sentence.

Also it could drop punctuation for example 'He was John, who came' should return 'John' and not 'John,'.

Comment: So, you only need `Doe` from `John Doe arrived late`?

Comment: What is definition of a sentence?

Comment: the sentence delimiter is either beginning of text or after dot+space.

Comment: yes because John is the start of the sentence I just need Doe. but if it the sentence was 'He, John Doe came here' then 'John Doe' should be returned.

Comment: How about this sentence `How are you Mr. Bean?` ?

Comment: The requirements are clear, so, where are you stuck?

Comment: How are you Mr. Bean should return ['Mr'] and ignore Bean because it makes it complicated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with regex particularly look-behind and look-aheads.

Comment: The above patterns doesn't consider consecutive capitals for example for 'He is John Doe.' returns ['John', 'Doe'] but should return ['John Doe'] (as mentioned in 'The President' example in the question).

Comment: ok then this one: [`(?<!\.\s)(?!^)\b([A-Z]\w*(?:\s+[A-Z]\w*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/wkjGnT/3)

Comment: This works great. If you make it an answer (and if you could kindly explain how different parts work) I could accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Afshin: No, it does not work great just because it does not *extract Named Entities*, it only extracts consecutive capitalized (with an ASCII letter only) words from a string of text not preceded with exactly `.` and any whitespace. It will fail once there are 2 whitespaces. It does not account for real sentence punctuation. This approximation might be good for you, but other future visitors will be misled.

Comment: You're right Wiktor, it doesn't solve the named entity problem. But is a lazy but fast approximation where I need high recall and don't care about precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this expression for this task:

```
(?<!\.\s)(?!^)\b([A-Z]\w*(?:\s+[A-Z]\w*)*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wkjGnT/3/)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?<!\.\s)` - Negative lookbehind to assert we don't have a DOT and space before
- `(?!^)` - Negative lookahead to assert we are not at start
- `\b` - Word boundary
- `(` - Start capturing group

  - `[A-Z]\w*` - Match a word starting with a capital letter
  - `(?:` - Start non-capturing group

    - `\s+` - Match 1 or more whitespaces
    - `[A-Z]\w*` - Match a capital letter word
  - `)*` End non-capturing group. Match 0 ore more of these
- `)` - End capturing group